# Counterexamples in Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence

I want to (dis)prove the following statement:

A sequence of functions which converges almost uniformly implies uniform convergence for that sequence of functions.

I'm sure I've read up on a counterexample for this. In particular I'm looking for a counterexample for the above statement, but with the added caveat that the above statement does hold on a set of either measure zero or measure less than $\varepsilon$

Comment: @par: Would something like $f_n(x)=x^n$ for $n\in[0,0.5]$ and $f_n(x)=x^n$ for $n\in (0.5,1]$ work? I understand what uniform convergence is since $x$ doesn't depend on epsilon, but I guess I am a bit confused about what almost uniform means

Comment: Wouldn't $1/x$ where $x$ is rational and $0$ where $x$ is irrational work? It certainly converges almost uniformly but uniform convergence is ruined by $1/x$ over $(0,\infty)$

Comment: http://store.doverpublications.com/0486428753.html

Comment: What is the def'n of "converges almost uniformly"?

Answer (score 2):

Try $f_n(x):=x^n$ on $[0,1]$ endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and Lebesgue measure. For any $\varepsilon$, we have the uniform convergence of the sequence $\left(f_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ on $[0,1]\setminus [1-\varepsilon,1]$, hence the almost uniform convergence.

However, we do not have the uniform convergence on $[0,1]$ and even on $[0,1]\setminus N$, where $N$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.